# Parser combinator validate multiple inputs

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

Suppose I have a snippet in a StandardTokenParser:

```
lazy val validWords = Set("param value","param2 value2")

lazy val paramNameCollectionToken = paramNameToken ~ rep(paramNameToken) ^^ {
     case head ~ rest => (head :: rest).mkString(" ")
}
```

How can I produce the list only if the result of head::rest is contained inside validWords Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is using `filter`.

```
val validToken: Parser[String] = paramNameCollection.filter(validWords)
```

If the filter predicate fails, the parser failure message will be generic, such as "Input doesn't match filter: ..."

The [source of filter](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.2/src/library/scala/util/parsing/combinator/Parsers.scala#L247) should contain some clues about how to customise this message.